# implicit derivation of hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

> derive $$\sinh(x+y)=\tanh^{-1}(\frac{x}{y})$$

$$\cosh(x+y)\cdot(1+f')=\frac{\frac{y-xf'}{y^2}}{1-(\frac{x}{y})^2}$$

$$\cosh(x+y)\cdot(1+f')=\frac{\frac{y-xf'}{y^2}}{\frac{y^2-x^2}{y^2}}$$

$$\cosh(x+y)\cdot(1+f')=\frac{y-xf'}{y^2-x^2}$$

$$(y^2-x^2)\cosh(x+y)\cdot(1+f')=y-xf'$$

$$(y^2-x^2)\cosh(x+y)+(y^2-x^2)\cosh(x+y)f'=y-xf'$$

$$((y^2-x^2)\cosh(x+y)+x)f'=y-(y^2-x^2)\cosh(x+y)$$

$$f'=\frac{y-(y^2-x^2)\cosh(x+y)}{(y^2-x^2)\cosh(x+y)+x}$$

is it correct?

Comment: What does $tgh^{-1}$ refer to in the first line?

Comment: You "derive" with respect to what?

Comment: It is arctgh, I derive with respect to x, sorry